# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So there is an error in my code. Error message is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null Error

Here is the Code:

**HTML:**

```
<section id="section-14">
    <div class="mediabox">
       <img src="product/Diffusers/Diffusers_1.jpg" alt="Diffusers">
       <h3>Diffusers</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('section-14').className = "content-current";
```

Someone please guide me about my mistake.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/hL7skno5/). Have you placed your JS just before `</body>`? That way it will wait until the DOM has loaded so you can ensure that you're actually targeting an element that's there. Or add an event listener to the document element and place your code in the corresponding function.

Comment: Are you running your `document.getElementById('section-14').className` code after the document is ready?

Comment: can you add your js file code. Your code for adding class is correct but i want to know where it is called

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Script at just before of the end of body tag. Your code should like this-

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<section id="section-14">
    <div class="mediabox">
       <img src="product/Diffusers/Diffusers_1.jpg" alt="Diffusers">
       <h3>Diffusers</h3>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
document.getElementById("section-14").className="content-current";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Or use `DOMContentLoaded`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is running before the DOM content is ready. That's why you cannot add a class to the `section-14` element. You'll have to include your script tag after the element or wait for the DOM to be ready using the `DOMContentLoaded` event, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('section-14').classList.add('content-current');
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementBy*ID*` does not exist. OPs problem is something different.

Comment: You're solving something that isn't the problem. Check my comment. His code works.